# Getting invalid XML using the v3 QBO customer API

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

v3 client SDK is blowing up with the message:
`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 24; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1c) was found in the element content of the document.`

...when running a CDC query over Customer.

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 24; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1c) was found in the element content of the document.]
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:512)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:209)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:175)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
at com.intuit.ipp.serialization.XMLSerializer.deserialize(XMLSerializer.java:59)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.DeserializeInterceptor.execute(DeserializeInterceptor.java:55)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeResponseInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:90)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:63)
at com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService.executeCDCQuery(DataService.java:359)
```

Comment: can you please share the response XML corresponding to this API call. JavaKit doesn't handle special character is a known issue. It should be fixed asap.

Comment: The response contains data I can't post. Any thoughts on when this will be fixed?

Comment: I don't know the exact fix date yet. Can you please raise a support ticket and share the XML response in that. It looks like it is more of a service issue rather than devkit one. Someone from dev-rel team will respond to your ticket asap.